# how to use date controls in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I am using Xcode(7.3.1) and MacOS EICaptian(10.11.4) and trying to create a sample project using with "date Controls" In that i tried below mentioned things but i am getting errors,
like "dateWithNaturalLanguageString is deprecated in os x 10.10" Instead of this What can i use.

```
var book:Book
override init() {
    book = Book()
    book.author = "Mr. Author"
    book.title = "The Book's Title"
    book.pageCount = 350
    book.publishDate = NSDate.dateWithNaturalLanguageString("03/20/1979") as! NSDate
```

and I created a custom class and I wrote this Code:

```
var author:String
var title:String
var pageCount:Int
var publishDate: NSDate

override init() {
    author = "author"
    title = "title"
    pageCount = 0
    publishDate = NSDate.date()
}
```

The error:

> date() is  unavailable:use object Construction NSDate().

Please help me out.

Comment: It's *in* the error message ...

Answer (score 0):

Swift compresses some initializers like `[SomeObject new]` becomes `SomeObject()`.

In your case it is `NSDate()`.

So your code would look like the following:

```
override init() {
    author = "author"
    title = "title"
    pageCount = 0
    publishDate = NSDate()
}
```